# Finding a point within a 2D triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm not sure how to approach the following problem and would love some help, thanks!

I have a two-dimensional triangle ABC for which I know the cartesian coordinates of points $A$, $B$ and $C$.

I am trying to find the cartesian coordinates of a point $P$. I know the lengths (distances) $PA$, $PB$ and $PC$.

How can I find the coordinates for $P$?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the vectors $AB$ and $AC$.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Take $\vec u=(b_1,b_2)-(a_1,a_2)$ and $\vec v=(c_1,c_2)-(a_1,a_2)$. If the 3 points are not collinear then the 2 vectors form a base. Or your point $P$ should be on the intersection of circles, since you have its distance from the vertices.

Comment: You can easily find the coordinates of P in the basis $\left(\overrightarrow{AB},\overrightarrow{AC}\right)$

Comment: Can you explain this further?

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x,y)$ be the coordinate of $P$ and $(x_i,y_i)$ be the coordinates of $A,B,C$ respec. $(i=1,2,3)$ Since you know the lengths of $PA, PB,PC$, you'll get three equations like $$(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2=d_{i}^2,\ i=1,2,3$$ Then, subtract the equation $i$ from equation $j$ to get something like $$x(x_i-x_j)+y(y_i-y_j)+x_i^2-x_j^2+y_i^2-y_j^2=d_i^2-d_j^2$$ From these equations solve for $(x,y)$ Actually only two lengths are enough to find out $P$. This method, for $3D$ is called [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation).

The equation that you'll get from point $A,B$ is $$x(x_1-x_2)+y(y_1-y_2)=-x_1^2-x_2^2+y_1^2-y_2^2+d_1^2-d_2^2\tag{1}$$

Similarly, equation that you'll get from $B,C$ is $$x(x_2-x_3)+y(y_2-y_3)=-x_2^2-x_3^2+y_2^2-y_3^2+d_2^2-d_3^2\tag{2}$$

So the equations are now in the form $$a_1x+b_1y=c_1\\
a_2x+b_2y=c_2$$
which have the solution $$x=\frac{b_2c_1-b_1c_2}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}\\
y=\frac{a_1c_2-a_2c_1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I'm not sure I understand the notation. What is equation j here?

Comment: $i$ is one of $1,2,3$ and $j$ is a different one.  Pick any two you like.  You have three equations in two unknowns, so one is redundant.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I'm very rusty here. Can you show how to solve these simultaneous equations? I'm used to code-like notation rather than mathematical notation. Thanks again!

Comment: @pt3dNyc to see how to solve simultaneous linear equations, please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations).

Comment: I'm stuck trying to isolate the variable. How do I isolate Px in the equation: Px = sqrt( sq( Wx ) - sq( ( sqrt( sq( Wy ) - sq(Px - Bx) ) + By ) - Ay ) ) + Ax

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome! @pt3dNyc